# Xamarin can't build Android Binding Project

Tags: binding, jar, xamarin

I'm trying to bind [the Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) jar to my project. I've already found [this link](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1156/adding-android-universal-image-loader-library). Which helped me to go down from 17 to 1 error. But I still get an error, which is different from all the other ones :

```
C:\wurth-reservation\Mobile\Wurth-Reservation\UniversalImage\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Imageaware.ImageViewAware.cs(23,23): Error CS0738: 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Imageaware.ImageViewAware'
does not implement interface member
'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Imageaware.IImageAware.WrappedView'. 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Imageaware.ImageViewAware.WrappedView' 
cannot implement
'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Imageaware.IImageAware.WrappedView' 
because it does not have the matching return type of 'Android.Views.View'. (CS0738) (UniversalImage)
```

I don't event know if I need to add something in the Medadata.xml file or create a Java method. What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.
I added the fallowing line in my Metadata.xml file :

```
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware']/class[@name='ImageViewAware']/method[@name='getWrappedView']" name="managedReturn">Android.Views.View</attr>
```